# How to align form inputs

Tags: html, css, alignment, forms, html-input

What is the best way to align form inputs next to labels

- without using a fixed label width, as this looks bad if the labels are much shorted then the specified length (especially when using a textarea in the same form, this looks [very bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnAQd.png))
- without using 2 columns (as inline div or table), one for labels and one for inputs, as this will [break responsive layouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT1SD.png) where label and input are on separate lines

Comment: Why would it break? 1)You want to have them inline on all screens? If so have them with two columns on mobile as well dont stack them.

Comment: Consider always placing the labels above inputs. Usability studies, such as [this older one](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2006/07/label-placement-in-forms.php), suggest this decreases the time taken for form completion.

Comment: @Sudheer Labels next to inputs on bigger screens, labels above inputs on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle..[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mqut6Lhk/1/)

```
 <label class="medium-inline">
   Label
 </label>
  <div class="medium-inline">
    <input type="text"/>
 </div>                                    


@media only screen and (min-width: 30em)  {
    .medium-inline{
        display:inline;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 30em)  {
    .medium-inline{
        display:block;
    }
}
```

All i did is change display property to inline and block respectively.

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to make use of flexbox and to set `flex:1` on the input to fill the remaining width of the container

### **[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/rsyugt1m/13/)**

**NB:** The above demo obeys the OP's constraint that no fixed width is set on the label.

If however `min-width` may be used on the label (corresponding to the longest label) then we can easily update the code to achieve a responsive / 2-column look:

### **[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/rsyugt1m/14/)**

```css
.container {
  width:80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 10px 0 0;
  /* min-width: 150px; (for demo 2) */
}
p {
  display: flex;
}
input {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.22);
  -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.22);
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.22);
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <p>
      <label>*First Name</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>*Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>*Label3</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Very very long label4</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```